# Reading and writing to the same file using the same fstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, iostream, fstream

I have a file that already contains some data (say, 8 kB). I want to read something from the beginning of the file, and then overwrite data starting where I finished reading. So I try to use the following code:

```
std::fstream stream("filename", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

char byte;
stream.read(&byte, 1);

// stream.seekp(1);

int bytesCount = 4096;

auto bytesVec = std::vector<char>(bytesCount, 'c');
char* bytes = bytesVec.data();

std::cout << stream.bad() << std::endl;

stream.write(bytes, bytesCount);

std::cout << stream.bad() << std::endl;
```

If I execute this code, the first `bad()` returns `false`, but the second one returns `true` and nothing actually gets written.

If I decrease `bytesCount` to anything smaller than 4096 (presumably the size of some internal buffer), the second `bad()` returns `false`, but still nothing gets written.

If I uncomment the `seekp()` line, the writing starts working: `bad()` returns `false` and the bytes actually get written.

Why is the `seekp()` necessary here? Why doesn't it work without it? Is the `seekp()` the right way to do this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are falling foul of a restriction upon the intermixing of read and
write operations on a file opened in update mode that MS's `fstream`
library inherits from from the its C `<stdio.h>` implementation.

The C Standard (I cite C99, but it doesn't differ in this point from C89)
at 7.19.5.3/6 states:

> When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
>   above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
>   associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek,
>   fsetpos, or rewind), and *input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function*, unless the input operation encounters end-
>   of-file.

(my emphasis).

So your `stream.seekp(1)` solution, which devolves to a C `fseek`, is correct.

The GNU C library does not have this Standard limitation, so your code as posted works
as expected when built with GCC.

The MS `<fstream>` library is compliant with the C++ Standard in inheriting
this restriction. `fstream`s are implemented using `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>`. In the (C++11) Standard's account of this template, at § 27.9.1.1/2, it simply says:

> The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an object of class basic_filebuf are the same as for reading and writing with the Standard C library FILEs.

Comment: Is this documented for C++ streams too? Or does MS implementation not follow the standard in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into tied streams - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/tie/

This makes every time an input reads the output will automatically be flushed, which is I think the behavior you want, although it does require a separate input and output stream