# Why does visual studio give another result than g++ ? Is Undefined behavior involved here?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, fstream

This C++ code is intended to move the data from 67 ~ 69 to 70 ~ 72 in the file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::fstream file("test", std::ios::out);
  file.close();
  file.open("test", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
  for (char i = 0; i < 127; ++i) 
    file.write(&i, 1);

  file.seekp(70);
  file.seekp(-3, std::ios::cur);

  char s[100];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    s[i] = '\0';

  file.read(s, 3);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    std::cout << (int)s[i] << " ";

  std::cout << std::endl;

  file.write(s, 3);
  file.seekp(-3, std::ios::cur);
  file.read(s, 3);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    std::cout << (int)s[i] << " ";

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The content of `s` should be the same in the two times I read it, just as the output if we compile the code in g++:

```
67 68 69
67 68 69
```

But the result in Visual Studio is different:

```
67 68 69
70 71 72
```

Is there any undefined behavior involved that leads to the bug? How should I fix it?

Comment: correct output with [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wIrSY51bPWxSu0Et)

Comment: Does this happen on Windows?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  But shouldn't the write-pointer and read-pointer of an `fstream` object always be at the same position?

Comment: @ZhiyangXun apparently not, read the documentation. I wasn't aware of this either.

Comment: @VTT yes, it's on Windows

Comment: Are there any reason for writing `i` variable address file.write(`&i`, 1); instead  of writing a byte value. G++ and MS  CL optimizing loops differ etc.

Comment: `basic_filebuf` specifies that *A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and the output sequence.*

Comment: first 3 lines in `main`: why???

Comment: I suggest you print the file position (`tellp` or `tellg`, perhaps *both*) before and after every seek, read and write. Also print the result of `gcount` after every read, and make sure that the file status is alright as well (`if (!file) { error... }`)

Comment: @AndriyTylychko `std::ios::in` requires the file to exist. See the table [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)

Comment: under VS `file.write(s, 3);` step fails or rather seems to write at 67 pos (even though output position is updated to 70), adding `file.seekp(70);` fixes the situation while `flush` does not

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17567454/560648 though I don't think that's the situation here as you are seeking. Still, the topic may provide some clues.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did what you suggested and `tellg` and `tellp` are always the same, and the result of `gcount` is also correct.  The file status is consistently alright as well.

Comment: Does it give you any hints about what's going on? Are the positions what you expect them to be?

Comment: @VTT Thank you so much! I've checked output position and tried flushing before writing but neither solved my problem. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I guess this is duplicated after all

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They are at the positions I expected to be... VTT's answer explains the situation.

Comment: @VTT But if I add a flush before writing, it will not violate the restriction. Why won't that solve the problem?

Comment: From answer to that question *"input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end- of-file."*

Comment: This should not have been closed.  MSVC is misapplying limitations on seeking in string buffers to the underlying file buffer.  See §30.8.2.4 [stringbuf.virtuals] where `cur`-relative seeks are defined to fail on `in|out` stringbuffers and §30.9.2.4 [filebuf.virtuals] where they're not, because you can (and do, here) have binary files where cur-relative seeks work, while  binary strings are still an oxymoron, at least in the C family.