# C++ program not inputting into a file

Tags: c++, input, fstream

This is what I currently have:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

fstream bookings("Schedule.txt");
fstream magicians("Magicians.txt");
fstream holidays("Holidays.txt");

//already tested to make sure these are open & they are

string test;
string holiday;

bookings >> test;

if(test.length()==0){
   while(getline(holidays, holiday)){
       bookings << holiday;
       cout << "test";

        }
    }

bookings.close();
magicians.close();
holidays.close();


  return 0;
}
```

My `Holidays.txt` contains this:

```
Veteran's Day
Valentine's Day
Halloween
Christmas
New Years
```

I've made sure my files are in the right directory and that the files are actually open. I stepped through the program to make sure `holiday` is getting the line accordingly but `bookings << holiday;` just doesn't seem to work properly for me?

Comment: Check file permissions? Should you add a << endl; to when you write to bookings?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to try to read from and write to a file at the same time. Do you just need to check if a file is empty? Try closing the file and reopening it before you write to it.

Comment: @FeiXiang it seems like he's trying to append the holiday file to the bookings file

Comment: OP, are you using Windows? Maybe take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536570/reading-and-writing-to-the-same-file-using-the-same-fstream#17567454

Comment: I'm using xcode. I had `<< endl;` previously too but that didn't work. The end goal of the program is to create a schedule with the holidays and then whatever magician are scheduled that day under them, hence I was importing the holidays first then I would check to see whether they're scheduled a certain day and then input the magician names into the schedule file accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    fstream bookings("Schedule.txt", ofstream::app);
    fstream magicians("Magicians.txt");
    fstream holidays("Holidays.txt");

    string holiday;

    while(getline(holidays, holiday)){
       bookings << holiday << "\n";
       cout << holiday << "\n";

    }

    bookings.close();
    magicians.close();
    holidays.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Mind explaining what exactly ofstream::app is doing?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, basically it will append the text to the file (adding at the end) rather than just rewriting over the previous contents, if that makes sense. If not [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) is more info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring your ifstream and ofstream variables first like you see below?

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

I use the following to open the input file before inputing contents into the stream.

inFile.open("input.txt");
outFile.open("toutput.txt");

I'm new to C++. Hope this helps.