# use fstream to read and write in the same time

Tags: c++, fstream

I am learning how to read and write from file . There is a problem that when I try to write (--something  in the file  letter for example--) after reading  or read after writing in the file
using `fstream`

something wrong is happening. I tried to just write or read and it worked. what is the problem?

the file content is :

```
abcdefgh
ijklmnopqr
stuvw
xyz
```

and the code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
fstream ioFile;
    char ch;
    ioFile.open("search.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    if (!ioFile)
    {
        cout << "problem opening the file";
        goto k270;
    }
    
    while (ioFile>>ch)
    {
        if (ch == 'z')
        {
            ioFile.seekp(((int)ioFile.tellg()));
             ioFile << "x";
            
            
        }
    }


    //cout<<ioFile.rdbuf();
    ioFile.close();
    k270:
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code will not overwrite the `z` in the file. Once you have read the `z` you're one position *beyond* the `z`, and it's this position that will be returned by `tellg()`. You need to get the position *before* you read the `z`. Or subtract one to go back to the `z`.

Comment: For future questions replace "something wrong is happening" with what is actually happening that is unexpected.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks for your feedback I will do that for future questions

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
okay you are right
I did that but when I write in the file the loop returns to the beginning of the file over and over again

Comment: Aside: write a char, not a string... "x" is a string.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès
okay I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17567454/11829247 it explains the error you are experiencing.

Short version: Input and output is buffered and interleaving reads and writes only work if you force buffer updates in between.

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::fstream ioFile;
    char ch;
    ioFile.open("search.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    if (!ioFile)
    {
        std::cout << "problem opening the file";
        return 1;
    }

    while (ioFile >> ch)
    {
        if (ch == 'z')
        {
            ioFile.seekp(-1, std::ios_base::cur);
            ioFile << "x";
            ioFile.flush();
        }
    }

    ioFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The difference is that I use `ioFile.seekp(-1, std::ios_base::cur);` to move one step back from the `cur`rent position. You could also use `ioFile.seekp((int)ioFile.tellg() -1);` - note the `-1`.

Then after stepping back and overwriting the z, use `ioFile.flush();` to force the write to be pushed to file. This also means that the read buffer is updated, without this the read operation just steps back in its buffer and keeps reading the same buffered z.